# Click functionality is not working in Angular formly custom template

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-formly

I am using `angular-formly` in my application. 
I defined a field with custom template which returns radio buttons.
On selecting a particular radio button `ng-click` is not working, call is not coming to my controller function. It would be great if someone helps me to get a solution for this issue.

```
$ctrl.fields =[{
      noFormControl: false,
      template: <div>
                  <input type="radio" ng-model="$ctrl.isPlacementCommon" value="true" onclick="$ctrl.changePlacementDisplay('true')">
                  <label>Place all VNFs on same resource</label>
                  <input type="radio" ng-model="$ctrl.isPlacementCommon" value="false" onclick="$ctrl.changePlacementDisplay('false')">
                  <label>Allow separate placement for VNFs</label>
                 </div>
    }
];
```

Comment: Can you try ng-click ?

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for the [`ng-change`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngChange) directive rather than `ng-click`.

i.e.
in your controller

```
$ctrl.changePlacementDisplay = function(val){
    //logic inside your changePlacementDisplay
};
```

then in your template

```
<input type="radio" ng-model="$ctrl.isPlacementCommon" value="true" ng-change="$ctrl.changePlacementDisplay(true)">
```

I took out the quotes around `true`. You can leave them if you'd rather passback a string.

If you continue to have issues and the ng-change function is not being called, I would suggest going back to the angular-formly docs. I'm unfamiliar with that library so I can't help there.